# working on a section within a text file in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am working on text files in Python and i am having difficulties in looping just a section of the text file, for example if i had a file like this:

```
     Hello my name is jason
     i am 25 and make 30,000 a year.
     this is the beginning.
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     this is the end
     thank you for reading my story.
```

Now i wanted to compute the section in between this is the beginning and this is the end, whilst being in a while loop.
So the code is

```
    while loop line != "":
       line = file.readline()
        if(line.find("beginning"):
            for line in range(line.find("beginning"), line.find("end"))
```

Now this obviously did not work but i was wondering if there is any suggestion on how i could possibly loop the lines in between those 2 sentences whilst still remaining in the overall loop?

Comment: What do you wan to do with the second loop? I'm not sure it would be necessary specifically? Do you just want to extract that text?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two boolean flags mark the beginning and ending.

cat sample.csv

```
Hello my name is jason
i am 25 and make 30,000 a year.
this is the beginning.
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
this is the end
thank you for reading my story.
```

cat test.py

```
BEGINNING = "this is the beginning"
ENDING = "this is the end"

with open("sample.csv", "r") as inputs:
    start_parsing, end_parsing = False, False
    for line in inputs:
        if BEGINNING in line.strip():
            start_parsing = True
            continue
        elif ENDING in line:
            end_parsing = True

        if start_parsing and not end_parsing:
            # do your work here...
            print(line.strip())
```

python test.py

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith("this is the beginning."): continue
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("this is the end."): break
            # do whatever you want to do for those specific lines
```

Comment: your `break` not work for the outer for loop. It processes all lines after `this is the end`

Comment: @haifzhan: it wasn't meant to.

Comment: can you please double check that, it is not only processing lines between `beginning` and `end`

Comment: @haifzhan: it will read every line in the file. I did that on purpose just in case there were multiple blocks in the file